# UITableViewcontentInset: when scrolling the table to the top, rows are still visible above first header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I've a table made of 1 header and 1 row in sequence:

```
Header
Row
Header
Row
```

I've set `contentInset` to lower the beginning position of the table the content:

```
self.detailTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(30.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

It works well, however, when scrolling the table, the content of the rows of the table is visible above the first header. Instead of disappearing, they are visible inside the top edge of 30 pixels. How to hide them instead? So that the scrolling works correctly.

Comment: can you please share a screenshot of the problem? it's not clear to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have sticky headers in the table view.

If you want to add padding on top you can just set the table header view:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 30))
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use multiple section like this to achieve what you want**

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
      return 2 ;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      if (section==0)
      {
             return [array1 count];
      }
      else{
             return [array2 count];
      }
 }

 - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      if(section == 0)
           return @"Section 1";
      else
           return @"Section 2";
 }


 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
      }

 if (indexPath.section==0) {
     ObjectData *theCellData = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
     cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
 }
 else {
     ObjectData *theCellData = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
     cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
 }
     return cell;        
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure we understood each other. My problem is that I need to hide the content of the table above the first header after scrolling. I don't want to change the structure of the table.

Comment: if you use section then it will hide header automatically